# loop through multiple rows and output related dataset SAS 9.4

Tags: macros, sas

I have a dataset, which is long data. Each subject has 52 week information.

The output I want is:

```
    data new1 new2 new3 ... new52;
    set old;
    if week = 1 then output new1;
       else if week = 2 then output new2;
       else....;
    run;.
```

Since there are 52 weeks,I want to write a macro. Don't know how to...

Comment: Why are you doing this? Often in SAS there are much better ways using BY group processing, it's really rare to need to split your data like this ever.

Comment: Thank you @Reeza. I am trying to get 52 dataset, and then merge them together to get a total dataset with 52 column. Is there a better way to do it? Please advise. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see the code below using macro to create 52 datasets..

```
data old;
do week=1 to 52;
output;
end;
run;

%macro new(i);
data new&i;
 set old;
 if week=&i then output;
run;
%mend new;

%macro loop;
%do j=1 %to 52;
 %new(&j);
%end;
%mend loop;

%loop;
```